# WPF: How can I use multiple list views in a control size correctly?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, wpf-grid

This is my XAML right now:

```
<Window x:Class="GridDemo.SubWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GridDemo"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView
        ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAnimal}"
        Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Button
        Command="{Binding AddAnimalCommand}"
        Content="Add Animal"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Grid.Row="1"/>
    <ListView
        ItemsSource="{Binding Vegetables}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVegetable}"
        Grid.Row="2"/>
    <Button
        Command="{Binding AddVegetableCommand}"
        Content="Add Vegetable"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Grid.Row="3"/>
</Grid>
```

When I run, it shows this:

[image]

Problem right away, it's using too much vertical space.

A thing I like and want to keep is that if I shrink it so that it's too small to show both listviews in their entirety, the listboxes shrink and automatically get scroll bars added, but the buttons stay visible no matter what.

[image]

But the main problem happens when the listviews are different sizes. They will always use half of the available space to them. Suppose I have ten animals and five vegetables, and my window is tall enough to hold 15 items. I would want the vegetable listview to ask for only as much space as it needs, letting the animal listview ask for all of the remaining space. Instead, both listviews ask for 50% of the remaining space, causing the animal listview to be too small and the vegetable listview to be too big.

[image]

I think that what I want is for the listview rows to behave like Height="Auto" when there's enough room for them, and to behave like Height="*" when there isn't.

Comment: Have you tried using `Height="Auto"` and setting a `MaxHeight` to your `RowDefinition` or `ListView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the effect you're looking for, I'd do something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="GridDemo.SubWindow" x:Name="win"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GridDemo"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window" Width="300">
    <Grid x:Name="grd">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition.Height>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource gpc}">
                        <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                            <Binding Path="Animals" />
                            <Binding ElementName="win" Path="ActualHeight" />
                        </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </RowDefinition.Height>
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition.Height>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource gpc}">
                        <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                            <Binding Path="Vegetables" />
                            <Binding ElementName="win" Path="ActualHeight" />
                        </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </RowDefinition.Height>
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAnimal}"
            Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button
            Command="{Binding AddAnimalCommand}"
            Content="Add Animal"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Grid.Row="1"/>
        <ListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding Vegetables}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVegetable}"
            Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Button
            Command="{Binding AddVegetableCommand}"
            Content="Add Vegetable"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Grid.Row="3"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I've used an implementation of `IMultiValueConverter` to generate the row height proportions. It's in a resource dictionary with a key of "gpc" and is implemented as follows:

```
public class GridProportionConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Count() == 2 && values[0] is ICollection && values[1] is double && ((ICollection)values[0]).Count > 0)
        {
            ICollection collection = (ICollection)values[0];
            double windowHeight = (double)values[1];

            if (windowHeight < 350)
            {
                return new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
            }

            return new GridLength(collection.Count, GridUnitType.Star);
        }

        return new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I have used `ICollection` assuming you have some kind of `ObservableCollection<T>` for your collections.

I find this works quite well, but obviously one thing it depends on is each `ListViewItem` being roughly the same height in each `ListView`, otherwise you may need to cater for the height difference.

I've also put a bit of a fail-safe in, where if the window's height goes below a certain value, the proportion becomes 1:1.

If the proportions are ever out of control, e.g., 300:1, you could always pass in both collections and calculate more appropriate proportions based on that, e.g., you might decide that 4:1 is the biggest difference you'd tolerate and you'd default to that if it ever got bigger.

Comment: Thanks! Got a new issue, though. I added this to the XAML
SizeToContent="Height"

Now the window starts at the correct size. But the proportions don't kick in properly until I resize the window. The simplest way to demonstrate this without changing your converter is to begin with 0 animals and 20 vegetables. Load the form and listview1 is almost completely collapsed. Begin resizing and listview1 instantly grows to about 20px.

(is there a better way to ask follow-up questions? I have a better example through code, but I don't want to get rid of the original question)

Comment: I'm not sure the two ways would be compatible. If you go back to just hardcoding `*` for both, you'll see that it doesn't pay any attention to that either (until you resize the window). You could play around with adding something like `if (collection.Count < 3) { return new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Pixel); }` to the converter (I put it after the windowHeight `if` block and it seems to work quite well).